# Java regex replaceAll with exclude pattern

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to make search keywords bold in result titles by replacing each keyword with `<b>kw</b>` using `replaceAll()` method. Also need to ignore any special characters in keywords for highlight. This is the code I'm using but it is double replacing the bold directive in second pass. I am looking for a elegant regex solution since my alternative is becoming too big without covering all cases. For example, with this input:

```
addHighLight("a b", "abacus")
```

...I get this result:

`<<b>b</b>>a</<b>b</b>><b>b</b><<b>b</b>>a</<b>b</b>>cus`

```
public static String addHighLight(String kw, String text) {
    String highlighted = text;
    if (kw != null && !kw.trim().isEmpty()) {
        List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(kw.split("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+"));
        for(String token: tokens) {
            try {
                highlighted = highlighted.replaceAll("(?i)(" + token + ")", "<b>$1</b>");
            } catch ( Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return highlighted;
}
```

Comment: FYI, Sets don't keep track of the order in which it their contents are stored, so I switched to a List, which does.  I also had to reverse your sample string (i.e. "a b") in order to reproduce your results.

Comment: I used Set to be little more efficient in case word is repeated. e.g for kw = a b b b a

Comment: I guessed as much.  And a Set should work fine because the order shouldn't matter.  I only changed it to a List to demonstrate that it **is** order sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't forget to use `Pattern.quote(token)`  (unless non-regex-escaped `kw` is guaranteed)
2. If you're bound to use `replaceAll()` (instead of tokenizing input into `tag|text|tag|text|...` and applying replace to texts only, which would've been much simpler and faster) - below code should help

Note that it's not efficient - it matches some empty or already-highlighted spots and thus requires "curing" after substitution, but should treat XML/HTML tags (except `CDATA`) properly.

Here's a "curing" function (no null checks):

```
private static Pattern cureDoubleB = Pattern.compile("<b><b>([^<>]*)</b></b>");
private static Pattern cureEmptyB = Pattern.compile("<b></b>");
private static String cure(String input) {
    return cureEmptyB.matcher(cureDoubleB.matcher(input).replaceAll("<b>$1</b>")).replaceAll("");
}
```

Here's how the replaceAll line should look like:

```
String txt = "[^<>" + Pattern.quote(token.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase()) + Pattern.quote(token.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()) +"]*";
highlighted = cure(highlighted.replaceAll("((<[^>]*>)*"+txt+")(((?i)" + Pattern.quote(token) + ")|("+txt+"))", "$1<b>$4</b>$5"));
```

Comment: @@Alan Moore - before editing it said "(except <pre>/CDATA)" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already excluding special characters from your keywords, the simplest way around this might just be to add a bit more to your search pattern. The following should prevent you from matching text that's already part of an html tag:

```
highlighted = highlighted.replaceAll("(?i)[^<](" + token + ")", "<b>$1</b>");
```

Comment: This gave me idea about lookbehind although not working completely.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me with minimum changes using regex lookbehind

```
highlighted = highlighted.replaceAll("(?i)((?<!<)(?<!/)" + token + "(?<!>))", "<b>$1</b>");
```

Comment: I don't think You'll like what that'd do to "</table>abacus"